# Sitecore List Manager only importing 15 contacts from CSV

Tags: list-manager

I have a CSV that contains 98 contacts. When I use the import contacts from csv option in List Manager, the output says "98 contacts imported". But when I go see the list I can only see 15 contacts there. Is there a limit being set to 15 contacts in one of the configs somewhere?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have duplicated emails (identifiers) in your csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were extending the built in import mapper for phone numbers. The code had a logic error and was returning null in certain cases. Unfortunately Sitecore was swallowing this exception internally and not erroring out and reporting that all contacts were imported. Once we fixed this logic error we were able to import the full contact list.